# How Do I Group Rows Together In A Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to distinguish the physical servers uptime from virtual ones by looking at OS. I am able to pull out the result of the VMWare OS, however, I'd like to group the physical servers as one row.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
   SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Avg(dbo.tblserveruptime.uptime) AS Uptime, 
                         Count(*)                        AS Total 
FROM   dbo.server 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblserveruptime 
               ON dbo.server.name = dbo.tblserveruptime.name 
WHERE  ( dbo.server.status = N'production' ) 
       AND ( dbo.server.server_env = N'prod' ) 
       AND ( dbo.server.os_type <> N'vmware' ) 
GROUP  BY dbo.tblserveruptime.month, 
          dbo.tblserveruptime.year 
HAVING ( dbo.tblserveruptime.month = 4 ) 
       AND ( dbo.tblserveruptime.year = 2013 ) 
UNION 
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Avg(dbo.tblserveruptime.uptime) AS Uptime, 
                         Count(*)                        AS Total 
FROM   dbo.server 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblserveruptime 
               ON dbo.server.name = dbo.tblserveruptime.name 
WHERE  ( dbo.server.status = N'production' ) 
       AND ( dbo.server.server_env = N'prod' ) 
       AND ( dbo.server.os_type = N'vmware' ) 
GROUP  BY dbo.tblserveruptime.month, 
          dbo.tblserveruptime.year 
HAVING ( dbo.tblserveruptime.month = 4 ) 
       AND ( dbo.tblserveruptime.year = 2013 )
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the output you get and the output you desire?

Comment: When you say *in one row* do you mean to `PIVOT` them?

Comment: Suppose you group all your physical servers into one row. Is *average uptime* still meaningful? Is *median uptime* meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever field it is that gives you the physical server name, add that field to your GROUP BY statement and put it first.  It will then group by Server, Month and Year (as you currently have it).  My guess is you might want to swap Year and Month as it makes more sense to do it that way than by Month and then Year.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to all who tried to help. I tried putting images of my before and after results, but I couldn't since I don't have 10 reputation points. Anyways, I think I got it. Here it is:

```
SELECT     AVG(dbo.tblServerUptime.Uptime) AS Uptime, 
CASE WHEN OS_TYPE = 'VMWare' THEN 'Virtual' ELSE 'Physical' END AS [Physical vs VM]
FROM         dbo.Server INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblServerUptime ON dbo.Server.NAME = dbo.tblServerUptime.NAME
GROUP BY CASE WHEN OS_TYPE = 'VMWare' THEN 'Virtual' ELSE 'Physical' END
```